# How to use ANCHOR SCROLL in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-routing, anchor-scroll

I have created a table with tabs using angular material and a box under the table.

When the user clicks one of the value in the table then the box which is under that should get enabled and scroll down to the bottom page where the box is located

I just used all the possibility ways which is done in JS but none works good

I tried this http://plnkr.co/edit/qIMIhIhqPymICTe0uzSh?p=preview

Below is the table, on a click of first value the box should get triggered

```
 <mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange) = "openState($event)">
        <mat-tab label="Closed Meetings">
          <mat-form-field id="filter">
            <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
          </mat-form-field>
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="this.dataSource"  class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="resource_name">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Resource Name</th>
              <td id="resurceName" mat-cell style="cursor: pointer" *matCellDef="let element" (click)="meetingInfo(element)">
              {{element.resource_name}}
              </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="meeting_id">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Meeting Id</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><a>{{element.meeting_id}}</a></td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="resource_Email">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Resource Email</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.resource_Email}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="contact">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Contact</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.contact}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="meeting_fd_link">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Meeting feedback link</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><a [routerLink]="['/b/signup-business']">
                {{element.meeting_fd_link}}</a></td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="meeting_time">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Meeting Time</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.meeting_time}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="rating">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Rating</th>
              <ul>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                  <li *ngFor="let i of element.rate">
                    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                  </li>
                </td>
              </ul>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="this.displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: this.displayedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>
        </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The box code

```
<div class="row" id="info" *ngIf="this.details">
  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3" id="heading">
  <h3>Meeting Information</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <p class="msg">Resource Name</p>
    <p class="msg"> Resource Email</p>
    <p class="msg"> Contact</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <p>: {{meetingDetails.resource_name}}</p>
    <p>: {{meetingDetails.resource_Email}}</p>
    <p>: {{meetingDetails.contact}} </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <p class="msg">Meeting Title</p>
    <p class="msg">Meeting Feedback Link</p>
    <p class="msg">Meeting Time</p>
    <button class="cncl" name="Submit" type="Submit" (click)="cancelMeeting(meetingDetails.meeting_id)">Cancel Meeting</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <p>: unavailable</p>
    <p>: unavailable</p>
    <p>: {{meetingDetails.meeting_time}} </p>
    <button class="resd" name="Submit" type="Submit">Reschedule Meeting</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll in a parent component.

Insert your table and box to separate component. Eg. `TableComponent` with selector `table-example`.
In TableComponent add `Output` with clicked event:

```
@Output() clickedInfo = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Next define table parent `div` size and add style `overflow: scroll`.
Add *template reference variable* (#scrollMe) on parent div.

Eg. template of your parent component:

```
<div #scrollMe style="overflow: scroll; height: 300px;">
  <table-example (clickedInfo)="clickedInfo($event)" ></table-example>
</div>
```

In parent component add `ElementRef` (with template reference variable).

```
@ViewChild("scrollMe") scrollMe: ElementRef;
```

Now when you receive clicked event, you can scroll to the box.
`scrollMe` ElementRef have `nativeElement.scrolTop` when you insert px position of top scroll. Insert to this variable height of whole component (from scrollMe.nativeElement.scrollHeight):

```
clickedInfo(event: string): void {
   this.scrollMe.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.scrollMe.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
}
```

Working example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cswfs

In the example *box* I also placed in a separate component.